# Year in Review 2016

Tags: discussion, statistics, year-in-review

In 2016, how did the Christianity Stack Exchange fare?  Are there any interesting trends or content worth sharing?

Comment: I would be interested to see a Year in Review for 2017, if you have the time to make one.

Comment: [Year in Review 2017](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6461/21576)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Trends

Overall site activity has declined somewhat since 2015.  We can see this through a few different metrics: traffic, new users, new content, and vote count.

**Traffic**

We've seen modest declines, around 12%, in visits, [according to Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/christianity.stackexchange.com?country=US#trafficCard):

```
           US      Rest of the world       Total
2015      5.6M          2.8M                8.4M
2016      4.8M          2.5M                7.4M
%chg      –14%          –11%                –12%
```

**New users**

Similarly, the number of [new users by quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/159325/count-new-users-per-month) (min. 2 rep) shows some decline as well, even accounting for seasonal differences:

```
             Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
2015        415    350    346    320 
2016        341    288    273    231
%chg       –18%   –18%   –21%   –28%
```

Some of the greater decline in the last couple quarters might be attributable to these new users not having the benefit of time to gain upvotes.

**New content**

We've seen a moderate decline in [questions asked](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2016) and a larger one in [answers given](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2016):

```
            Questions     Answers     Total
2015           1351         3399       4750
2016           1181         2211       3392
%chg           –13%         –35%       –29%
```

**Votes**

The [number of upvotes and downvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/610272/vote-count-by-time-period?Start=2015&End=2016) has also declined:

```
          Upvotes      Downvotes      Total
2015       22831         10345        33176
2016       17479          7012        24491
%chg        –23%          –32%         –26%
```

Given the decline in new content, it's perhaps unsurprising that the number of votes has fallen as well.  That said, we might expect the increasing size of the repository to attract more votes from new users.

## Content and users

On a happier note, we've seen many examples of generous users and highly voted content.

**Generosity**

- **Simply a Christian** gave away the most reputation in bounties this year
- **curiousdannii** had the highest Votes to Reputation ratio among qualified users (0.78).  Runners up were **bruised reed** (0.63) and **KorvinStarmast** (0.56).

  - These users had at least 500 votes and 500 reputation earned in 2016.  Among those just missing these minimums, the highest ratio belongs to **Thunderforge**, at 0.99.
  - This metric indicates dedication to the community (via one of its most important mechanisms, voting) with relatively little reward in reputation.

**Top New Questions and Answers**

[Top 10 questions of 2016](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20score%3a13%20created%3a2016%20closed%3ano) by score:

- [According to those holding that Lazarus was literally raised from the dead, why did Matthew, Mark, and Luke not mention it?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/52179/21576)
- [Why are psalms in the bible printed with funny spacing?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46821/21576)
- [Why does the Salvation Army not administer the sacraments of baptism and the Lord's Supper?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48952/21576)
- [Why did John Newton oppose Handel's Messiah?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/52213/21576)
- [What is the basis for forbidding prerecorded music in worship services?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50787/21576)
- [What is the earliest use of the phrase “God the Son”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/47889/21576)
- [Did Tertullian forbid Christians from being school teachers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48314/21576)
- [What does the abbreviation “RNIO” mean in a painting of the Virgin and Child?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/47442/21576)
- [When is the first time in church history we find a prayer ending with “in Jesus' name, amen”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50972/21576)
- [Who first described Pentecost as a reversal of Babel?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48724/21576)

Several of the [top 10 answers of 2016](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A16+created%3A2016) appear as answers to one of the above questions.  Those that do not are listed separately here:

- [Is there more than one Joseph in the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/47620/21576)
- [Which tribe did Paul belong to?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/47538/21576)
- [Would reading “The Street Bible” help me understand the KJV Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/48976/21576)
- [What is the Biblical basis for using the names “Yeshua” and “Yehoshua” (Joshua) for Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/46243/21576)
- [Can any sin be forgiven? (According to the teaching of the Catholic Church)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/53756/21576)
- [Has a parable originally used by Jesus been left out of Luke 14? [closed]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52444/21576)

And finally, here are the [top 6 *unanswered* questions of 2016](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0%20score%3a7%20created%3a2016), by score:

- [Why did the Presbyterian Church of Korea split in 1959?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46524/21576)
- [Why Was Jesus Represented as Being Born in a Cave?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54300/21576)
- [What's the source of the “new world religion” memorandum signed in Strasbourg?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/52508/21576)
- [Is there a recognised soteriology that combines selective election for some and general election for everyone else?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48302/21576)
- [Are the five propositions condemned by Cum occasione in the Augustinus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/53535/21576)
- [Why does the Roman Catholic Church not hold to the perspicuity of Scripture?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54274/21576)

## Summary

This cursory review reveals moderate declines in key metrics like traffic, content, and community involvement (via vote count).  Even so, we have numerous examples of dedicated community members, including many who give (via voting) more than they receive (in reputation).  We also have seen a wide variety of highly regarded content, both questions and answers.

Now let's make 2017 even better!

Comment: I'm going to look into this more, but for now a word of caution: I don't think the "decline" you're seeing is necessarily indicative of anything. At the very beginning of the year there was a huge shake up in the search engine world and we lost a ton of traffic overnight due to not showing up the same way as before. I'm pretty sure we've been steadily growing through 2016, but the baseline new visitor traffic got moved right after the first of the year — something that really doesn't reflect on the health of the site as much as a first blush might suggest.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb. I didn't feel qualified to  provide much analysis on the data I found, but something like what you are talking about certainly makes sense. And even if there is a true "decline," that's not necessarily a bad thing either -- it might indicate higher quality standards and a focusing of our niche.

Comment: Pageview traffic took a massive hit virtually overnight in the last 2 weeks of December last year to the tune of 30% or so of new visitor traffic. I haven't found a source but I remember SE at the time letting us know it was a change in Google page rank calculations that took this chunk. After that the next few months have a lot of jitter, but the trend since July is up again. So the 10–15% loss you show for the year is actually a 15–20% gain over the year if you figure the December 2015 "reset" as the year starting point.

Comment: That being said the contribution activity numbers you're looking at (posts, votes) seem to line up pretty well with what I have access to. I'd say the vote number at least is cause for concern. We might want to try to get the "vote early vote often" mantra in front of some of our newer site visitors. The more votes flow the more effective the crowd sorting mechanism becomes and the more motivated people are to keep contributing.